# Seasonal Plot change of labels on the x axis in R

Tags: r, plot, label, axis-labels

I would like to change the name of the labels on the X axis to Polish months. I have a simple example with Air Passengers data.

```
library(forecast)

ggseasonplot(AirPassengers)
```

[image]

I tried to use `scale_x_datetime()` or `scale_x_discrete`, but I got errors. 
Is there any way to solve my problem?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use the `season.labels` argument to set the labels to whatever you prefer. I've just used numbers for months, but you can substitute it with Polish labels.

```
library(forecast)

ggseasonplot(AirPassengers, season.labels = 1:12)
```

[image: example]